# Getting a substring of a dataframe column

Tags: java, apache-spark

In a spark dataframe (Java API version 2.2), I am trying to get the substring of a column as follow:

```
//aggregationDS is a spark dataset
aggregationsDS = aggregationsDS.withColumn("NODE_ID", aggregationsDS.col("NODE_ID").substr(2, [*Lengthofcolumn*]));
```

I need to feed the length of the string for that particular column but not sure what is the correct command.

Comment: You can use [substring inbuilt function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#substring-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-int-int-) for that

Comment: yes, but how to get the length for the second parameter?

Comment: yes,Spark java API

Comment: Java API, not pyhton or scala.

Comment: udf function should help you. But since I am not good in Java Api I am unable to help you further

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `expr`:

```
aggregationsDS.withColumn("NODE_ID", expr("substr(NODE_ID, 2)") );
```

or

```
aggregationsDS.withColumn("NODE_ID", expr("substr(NODE_ID, 2, length(NODE_ID))") );
```